# What would be an appropriate intra-rater reliability method for just 3 items test-retest

Tags: repeated-measures, continuous-data, reliability

I had 20 raters evaluating 35 items with continuous interval scores. 3 items (randomly chosen out of the 35 for each rater) were tested at the beginning and then again at the end of the session. I want to see how consistent the raters remain through out the session. I have examined the Mean Square Errors which appear pretty low, but maybe there is a more appropriate method to do it? I am not looking for absolute agreement, just good similarity of intra-rater scores at the beginning and the end of the session.